# Grails REST with @Resource - PUT is not updating

Tags: rest, grails

I'm learning grails (2.4.0) right now and have a weird problem with automatically generated REST methods.

So, i have a simple domain

```
@Resource(uri = '/unit', formats = ['json'])
class Unit {
    String name;
}
```

I can successfully list/create/delete instances with GET/POST/DELETE methods, but PUT method does nothing:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"fail", "id":65}' localhost:8080/app/unit/65
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://localhost:8080/app/unit/65
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 01 Jun 2014 09:25:02 GMT

{"class":"app.Unit","id":65,"name":"test"}
```

subsequent GET requests will also return name:test instead of name:fail

What i can be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which only relates to updates (not to newly created instances).  I have worked up the fix and we will have this fix included in 2.4.1.  See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11462.

The short of it is that updates are being done with the request parameters, even if the request has a body.  The fix is to change that so when the update is done, if the request has a body then the body is used and if it does not, the request a parameters are used.

Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the input.

Comment: Jeff, you wrote ... the body is used ... -- Used for what?

Comment: @Juriy used as the data binding source.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for explanation. I use grails 2.4.3 and still have this bug. Have to use request.JSON and far that way to get the domain class instance.