# Grails: REST PUT JSON Optimistic Locking member "version" not being received

Tags: json, grails, grails-controller

Using Grails 2.3.9

I'm trying to deal with versioning on domain objects. Grails (or Hibernate) supports a version member on domain classes by default (which is also reflected in the DB). When making PUT requests with json that contains "version", on the controller side it always has `params.version == null`. The only way I can pass the "version" parameter is by URL argument (like: /item?version=12)

Is it not possible to sent the version with the other fields like e.g. `{"name": "abc", "version":12}`?

Update: it should mean that when sending "version" as part of the data during a PUT request, this value is not filled when doing a `instance.properties = params` (while all other domain member variables are). It seems that since "variable" is automatically generated it is somehow not visible during the populating `instance.properties = params` (?!).

Comment: Have you tried getting version from the JSON request payload instead? `request.JSON.version`. This might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978443/grails-rest-with-resource-put-is-not-updating and [this bug](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11263) which will be fixed in 2.4.1. Refer [this discussion](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/RestfulController-problem-td4656494.html) for more insight.

Comment: The declared members of a domain class are received. Just the automatically generated "version" (and other non member variables) is not. I think, the problem described in the SO question is different.

Comment: There is something I totally don't understand. If I try to read `request.JSON.version` at the beginning of the controller's update() method, it has something; if I do it later (after `instance.properties = params`) then the request.JSON object is empty.